# Owner doesn't change after using terminal instructions properly

Tags: command-line, permissions

I want to copy a file to a folder called "Modules". I opened in the folder that contains that one and used:

```
sudo chown -R danielyeste Modules
```

When I access the properties, root still has the ownership.

danielyeste is my user, checked with `whoiam` in terminal.

Also tried to do it with `sudo mv` and other options.

Full path is:

```
/snap/clion/current/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.16/Modules
```

Comment: You can't `chown` files in a snap. Copy them first to somewhere else and then `chown` them.